# "Missing input file: 'mem110.clo'" on Travis CI build

Tags: texlive, memoir, compiling, installing

I'm trying to build [this repo](https://github.com/grulg/test-thesis) with Travis CI, using latexmk and pdflatex. Works fine locally, but when it tries to compile on Travis, I get the following error message ([entire log](http://pastebin.com/TPyVigyY)):

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mem110.clo' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: clo)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.736         \input{mem1\@ptsize.clo}
                                      ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on demothesis.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'mem110.clo' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `mem110.clo' not found.'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 256
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing.
```

To my understanding, `mem110.clo` is part of the Memoir class that my thesis template is based on, and it should be included in the TeX-live package on Ubuntu.

And here's the .travis.yml:

```
language: bash
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends texlive-full latexmk

install: true

script:
  - latexmk demothesis.tex -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -jobname=demothesis

before_deploy:
  - if [ -z ${TRAVIS_TAG+x} ]; then echo "TRAVIS_TAG is unset."; else mv demothesis.pdf demothesis_$TRAVIS_TAG.pdf; fi

deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: <token>
  file: demothesis_$TRAVIS_TAG.pdf
  on:
    tags: true

branches:
  only: master
```

Any ideas of how I can get it to compile on Travis?

Comment: Welcome! `mem110.clo` does not exist in TeX Live. `mem11.clo` exists and `mem10.clo` exists, but there is no support for a default font size of 110pt. Impossible to say why it is looking for this without an MWE, however.

Comment: As you haven't shown any of your code my guess is that you have a typo in your `\documentclass[...]{memoir}` line, probably the pointsize option.